# Extracting JSON data into a relational table

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file which resulted from YouTube's iframe API and needs to be preprocessed. I want to put this JSON data into a pandas dataframe, where each JSON key will be a column, and each recorded "event" should be a new row.

I was able to load the data as a dataframe using the *read_json* , but with this the keys for each event are shown as an array.

Here is what my JSON data looks like :

```
{  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "timemillis":1563467463580,
         "date":"18.7.2019",
         "time":"18:31:03,580",
         "name":"Player is loading",
         "data":""
      },
      {  
         "timemillis":1563467463668,
         "date":"18.7.2019",
         "time":"18:31:03,668",
         "name":"Player is loaded",
         "data":"5"
      }
]
}
```

And this is what I did to convert it to a dataframe:

```py
data=pd.read_json("file.json")
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

The output looks like this:

```
0  {'timemillis': 1563469276604, 'date': '18.7.20...
1  {'timemillis': 1563469276694, 'date': '18.7.20...
...
```

How can I convert this output into a table where I have separate columns for these keys such as 'timemmillis','date','name' and so on? I never worked with JSONs before so I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json("file.json",orient='columns')
rows = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    rows.append({'eventid':i+1,'timemillis':r['events']['timemillis'],'name':r['events']['name']})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

Now you can insert this df to database

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working but do you know if there is a way to prevent the alphabetical sorting of the columns?

Comment: You can add column names while creating DataFrame, e.g df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['name','timemillis','eventid'])

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "timemillis":1563467463580,
         "date":"18.7.2019",
         "time":"18:31:03,580",
         "name":"Player is loading",
         "data":""
      },
      {  
         "timemillis":1563467463668,
         "date":"18.7.2019",
         "time":"18:31:03,668",
         "name":"Player is loaded",
         "data":"5"
      }
]
}

# or read data from file
# rather than reading file directly to pandas dataframe read as json
# data=pd.read_json("file.json")


with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data['events'])
    print(df)
```

Result

```
data       date               name          time     timemillis
0       18.7.2019  Player is loading  18:31:03,580  1563467463580
1    5  18.7.2019   Player is loaded  18:31:03,668  1563467463668
```

Comment: Thank you, interestingly when I copy-paste the JSON data like you did into a "data" variable, I get the desired output. However, when I try to read the data from file it doesn't work, and I get the same output as I did in the beginning.

Comment: read file as json, rather directly as dataframe. I am editing my answer for it.